# Are UDP packets "retransmitted" when dropped by an edge router inside an SSH Tunnel?

Tags: udp, ssh, packet-loss

A network architect was recently asking about enabling DSCP on tunnels that I create for a VPN-like solution I maintain using ssh to maintain tunnels on linux devices. I thought this was odd because I thought we'd just retransmit anything that failed.

So my question is are UDP packets "retransmitted" when dropped by an edge router inside an SSH Tunnel?  Meaning, are the ssh packets retransmitted because routers have no idea that they're UDP under the hood and ssh clients and servers don't care that they're UDP.

Answer (score 2):

No IP packets are retransmitted by a router when dropped, regardless of what payload they carry - UDP, TCP or another payload doesn't matter.

Retransmissions may happen at the transport layer for protocols that support delivery tracking like TCP does. Those datagrams are retransmitted by the source host, not a router.

Answer (score 1):

From the perspective of the OS it is only relevant that TCP is a reliable protocol and thus it will do retransmission if packets are lost. It does not matter what is inside the SSH tunnel.